# Get user AD groups from other domain

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory

I have problems with UserPrincipal.GetGroups() and GetAuthorizationGroups() method. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. The problem is that in the unsuccesfull cases the method contacts bad AD domain. My dev PC is connected to company
domain and I want to get groups for user in other, test domain, where the PC isn't in.

My code:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.int", "user1@test.int", "pwd123");
ctx.ValidateCredentials("user1@test.int", "pwd123"); //returns always true
var adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, "user1@test.int");
var groups = adUser.GetAuthorizationGroups(); //sometimes exception...
```

It raises ActiveDirectoryServerDownException - RPC server is unavailable. It is because 
in this case the method call wanted to communicate with a company DC server, not with the 
test domain!

My dev environment:
- server: DC+DNS server W2003, single-DC domain "test.int", the DNS has "company.int" DNS as its forwarders, but same problem, if the forwarders are disabled.

- my PC: connected to "company.int" domain, uses only DNS server of the test DC, same LAN network as the server

I didn't found way, how to force to connect always to the test DC server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetAuthroizationGroups()` won't work if you are from an untrusted domain.  It is because underlying it's calling Authz.dll.  I just tried it in my two test domains without trust.  It fails and throws me exception with the following callstack

```
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet..ctor(Byte[] userSid, NetCred credentials, ContextOptions contextOptions, String flatUserAuthority, StoreCtx userStoreCtx, Object userCtxBase)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOfAZ(Principal p)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroupsHelper()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()
at TestDomain.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Testbench\TestDomain\TestDomain\Form1.cs:line 69
```

I disassemble `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll`.  Here is the code.  I think it's failing at `AuthzInitializeContextFromSid`.

```
[SecurityCritical]
internal AuthZSet(byte[] userSid, NetCred credentials, ContextOptions contextOptions, string flatUserAuthority, StoreCtx userStoreCtx, object userCtxBase)
{
    this.currentGroup = -1;
    this.contexts = new Hashtable();
    this.localMachineIsDC = null;
    this.userType = userStoreCtx.OwningContext.ContextType;
    this.userCtxBase = userCtxBase;
    this.userStoreCtx = userStoreCtx;
    this.credentials = credentials;
    this.contextOptions = contextOptions;
    this.flatUserAuthority = flatUserAuthority;
    this.contexts[flatUserAuthority] = userStoreCtx.OwningContext;
    IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr rm = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        UnsafeNativeMethods.LUID identitifier = new UnsafeNativeMethods.LUID();
        identitifier.low = 0;
        identitifier.high = 0;
        this.psMachineSid = new SafeMemoryPtr(Utils.GetMachineDomainSid());
        this.psUserSid = new SafeMemoryPtr(Utils.ConvertByteArrayToIntPtr(userSid));
        int num = 0;
        bool flag = UnsafeNativeMethods.AuthzInitializeResourceManager(UnsafeNativeMethods.AUTHZ_RM_FLAG.AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, null, out rm);
        if (flag)
        {
            flag = UnsafeNativeMethods.AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(0, this.psUserSid.DangerousGetHandle(), rm, IntPtr.Zero, identitifier, IntPtr.Zero, out zero);
            if (flag)
            {
                int pSizeRequired = 0;
                flag = UnsafeNativeMethods.AuthzGetInformationFromContext(zero, 2, 0, out pSizeRequired, IntPtr.Zero);
                if ((!flag && (pSizeRequired > 0)) && (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 0x7a))
                {
                    buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pSizeRequired);
```

As you can see above, the `NetCred credentials` is passed in and never used.  It's calling the [AuthzInitializeContextFromSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) right away.  If you check MSDN, they have the following disclaimer.

> **Important** Applications should not
>   assume that the calling context has
>   permission to use this function.

I cannot explain why it sometimes works on your environment and sometimes doesn't.  It's always not working in my environment.  I guess one possible reason is that you visited the untrusted domain controller from your workstation and pressed "stored credentials".  This will store the network credentials and whenever you contact that particular machine, Windows will automatically uses the stored credentials for you.  Another possible reason is that you are using the same password with the same username in those two domains.

To walkaround the problem, I simply use `GetGroups()` on the users and then calling `GetGroups()` on all its groups.  Repeat it until you reach the top level group.  You may also like to check if it's a security group.  You may like to simply skip all the distribution groups.  The `GetGroup()` method returns you both security groups and distribution group.

Comment: Ok, recursive call of GetGroups() looks to be working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to use the **NetBIOS** domain name on the `PrincipalContext` - not any DNS-style domain names.

So change this:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.int", "user1@test.int", "pwd123");
                                                   ***********
```

to something like:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "INTTEST", "user1@test.int", "pwd123");
                                                   ***********
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for hint, but the error is the same... I hope I made it correctly - I installed WINS server on the test DC controller, added record: INTTEST (it wasn't created automatically - only the DC server name and my dev PC name was registered automatically by the WINS server).